# Installed Apps not showing in Cellular Allow Data for section

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, cellular-data

I have iphone 5s , IOS 9.3.1

All the apps like whatsapp , facebook , twitter , skype etc from IOS Store are installed in my iphone and is available in Background app refresh section

But all those apps are **not appearing in "Allow Data For" section** in cellular section in IOS.

[image] 
[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Comment: None of these steps have helped. I've tried every single one and nothing has worked. What do I do. Downgrade back to iOS 8? Or wait for a new update.

Comment: i have posted an answer which helped me. have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those apps appears in that section when i turn the data on and use some apps from the data. Each app when takes the data connection and use it start appearing in the section. Once it appears in that section i was able to remove it from there.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same solution as the writer before me. The "mobile data" part of your phone doesnt know app's exists until you use mobile data on them... IE I had downloaded snapchat using wifi and had my phone in airplane mode... i didnt use mobile data for snapchat and so snapchat never showed up in the list of apps that you can turn mobile data on and off for... as soon as i was out of wifi range and used snapchat, the app showed up and I could turn the mobile data off...

Comment: there should be way to block all the things and system services using data and only allow some apps and services to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some steps you can use to try to fix this.  Credit goes [here](http://appletoolbox.com/2015/09/ios-9-cellular-data-usage-settings-not-working-fix/):

- Confirm cellular data is enabled by going to `Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data`
- Try turning **Airplane** mode on and off again by going to `Settings > Airplane Mode`
- Go to `Settings > General > Restrictions > Cellular Data Use`, make sure “**Don’t Allow Changes**” is toggled off, then tap `Settings > Cellular`, then turn **Cellular Data** to **OFF**, wait a few seconds, then turn **Cellular Data** back to **ON**
- Reset Network Settings by going to  `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings`
- Reboot your device.
- Uninstall and install any problem app.

If nothing above helps you, you could try this:

- Back up your device (`Settings > iCloud > Backup > Back Up Now`)
- You can see your recent back ups by going to `Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage`
- Restore your device. **Important this will erase everything**. This is why you should back up first.
- Connect your device to your computer. In **iTunes**, select your device, and click **Restore**.
  Your device will restart. Simply follow the setup assistant and set it up as *NEW*, **don’t set up from a backup** because it is highly likely that this problem is due to corrupt information, this means that problem will repeat if you restore from a backup. We will restore your device from iCloud later.
- Now verify that the problem is resolved
- After verifying, now restore your iCloud backup. To do this, go to `Settings > General > Reset > Erase all content and settings`.
- When your device restarts, tap `Restore from a Backup`.

Comment: i have tried the first way of step , that didnt help i think i have to reset the device. The only thing that matters to me is whatsapp backup , my contacts and messages. Does it still require for me to restore from itunes and then reset all content and settings. ? cant i just reset and don't restore from backup and get my contacts and message back and install whatsapp and get that backup from icloud ?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to restore if you already have Contacts backed-up to iCloud.  In fact, it would probably be better not to restore so you don't put whatever is causing your problem back on to your device.

Comment: ok thank you what about whatsapp backup, if i dont restore it will it ask for that whatsapp backup when i use whatsapp to restore that backup ?

Comment: I don't know about that, I've never used whatsapp.  I would assume that as long as you're backing it up to iCloud in Settings, it should bring your data back when you restore.  However, don't take my word for it because, like I said, I don't use that app.

Comment: ii have tried and reset it , still no non native apps appearing only same apps appearing in the cellular section.

Comment: When you go into `Settings` and tap on the individual apps, do they have their own `Allow Cellular` switch?  Maybe you need to turn it on there in order to have it show-up in the iPhone **Cellular** setting?  Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: i only see background app refresh bar in app settings.

Comment: Are you sure you can turn off cellular data for WhatsApp?  I did some quick searching and it doesn't seem that WhatsApp was coded to appear in `Cellular` settings.  Some apps just don't appear because they're not coded to be there, maybe this is the case here.